# Extraer de un texto las concidencias de asc y desc en php usando regexpr

Tags: php, regex

Estoy intentando extraer de una cadena si hay una concidencia de las siguientes palabras, `asc` y `desc`

la idea es procesar la siguiente entrada `sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email)` y de aquí extraer el nomber de campo y la direción.

lo que tengo

```php
<?php

$s = "sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email)";

$field = extractSortFields($s);
print_r($field);

$directions = extractSortDirection($s);
print_r($directions);

function extractSortField($s) {
    preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

function extractSortFields($s) {
    preg_match_all('~\(([^()]*)\)~', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

function extractSortDirection($s) {
    preg_match_all('?pattern para extraer asc y desc', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
```

retorna

```
Array
(
    [0] => last_modified
    [1] => email
)
```

ahora me falta que $directions sea

```
Array
(
    [0] => desc
    [1] => asc
)
```

o sino ya lo ideal seria tener un array associativo

```php
Array
(
    ['last_modified'] => desc
    ['email'] => asc
)
```

Comment: Para complementar otra variante siguiendo sort filter RHS colon, https://onlinephp.io/c/9727a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que son dos constantes, puedes simplemente usar `(asc|desc)` básicamente estás diciendo que obtenga lo que haga match con cualquiera de los dos. El único problema sería si por ejemplo tuvieras `asc(description)` Te haría doble match, por lo que tendrías que especificar la forma en que es válido `asc` y `desc`, es decir `/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/`

Entonces tu función quedaría así

```
function extractSortDirection($s) {
    preg_match_all('/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
```

puedes probar con `$s = "sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email),desc(asc)";` y verás que solo te regresa 3.

Personalmente creo que podría funcionar mejor lo siguiente. dado que te ayudaría a verificar que efectivamente vengan de esa forma los `fields`

Primero hacer `split` a la cadena.

```
$s = "sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email),desc(asc)";
$s_split = explode(',', $s);
```

Validar que cada `field` esté de la forma correcta

Para eso creamos dos funciones `validateSortField` que te dice si viene en la estructura correcta.

```
function validateSortField($field) {
    return preg_match('/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/', $field);
}
```

Y `extractSortDirection` que te extrae si es `asc` o `desc`

```
function extractSortDirection($s) {
    preg_match('/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
```

Luego simplemente iterar sobre la cadena spliteada y ver si es valido guardarlo en un arreglo.

```
$data = [];
foreach ($s_split as $field) {
    if (validateSortField($field)) {
        $data[extractSortField($field)] = extractSortDirection($field);
    }
}
```

Eso te regresará

```
Array
(
    [last_modified] => desc
    [email] => asc
    [asc] => desc
)
```

La ventaja de esta forma es que si haces algo como esto

```
$s = "sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email),desc(asc),pos(id),id,asc()";
```

Puedes compara las respuestas.

**Segunda forma**

```
Array
(
    [last_modified] => desc
    [email] => asc
    [asc] => desc
)
```

**Primer forma**

```
Array
(
    [0] => last_modified
    [1] => email
    [2] => asc
    [3] => id
    [4] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => desc
    [1] => asc
    [2] => desc
    [3] => asc
)
```

Te dejo el código completo.

```
<?php

$s = "sort_by=desc(last_modified),asc(email),desc(asc),pos(id),id,asc()";
$s_split = explode(',', $s);

$data = [];

foreach ($s_split as $field) {
    if (validateSortField($field)) {
        $data[extractSortField($field)] = extractSortDirection($field);
    }
}

print_r($data);

$field = extractSortFields($s);
print_r($field);

$directions = extractSortDirections($s);
print_r($directions);


function validateSortField($field) {
    return preg_match('/(asc|desc)\((.+?)\)/', $field);
}

function extractSortField($s) {
    preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

function extractSortFields($s) {
    preg_match_all('~\(([^()]*)\)~', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

function extractSortDirections($s) {
    preg_match_all('/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

function extractSortDirection($s) {
    preg_match('/(asc|desc)\((.*?)\)/', $s, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
?>
```